# Map Function - Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object evaluating map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a file called displayKeyHelpers.ts  and the `members.map` code is on line 118. The code works for most users and in QA as well but occasionally it seems members is undefined. I am looking at a crash report that says

```
displayKeyHelpers.ts, line 118
SIGABRT: Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n.map') This error is located at: in V in Unknown in Unknown in Unknown..
```

It seems like members in the function below is undefined. How can I add a check?

```
export const memberDropdownOptions = (members: any): Option[] => {
  const options: Option[] = []
  members.map((member: Person) => {
    options.push({
      label: `${member.firstName} ${member.lastName}`,
      value: member.dependentNumber,
    })
  })
  return options
}
```

This is what I tried but it failed some unit tests so I am guessing that it is not right:

```
export const memberDropdownOptions = (members: Person[]): Option[] => {
  const options: Option[] = []
  members?.map((member: Person) => {
    options.push({
      label: `${member?.firstName} ${member?.lastName}`,
      value: member?.dependentNumber,
    })
  })
  return options
}
```

The function is used like this:

```
const memberOptions = memberDropdownOptions(members)
```

Comment: If you don't want to change your unit tests, you need to check your input values for this function. How do you call this function?

Comment: this is obvious) But you are probably passing an `undefined` value. So the error should be looked for in the code of the component that calls this function. You can also try to change the function signature as in the second option - `const memberDropdownOptions = (members: Person[]): Option[]`. In this case, the error will be clearer

Answer (score 1):

The `members` argument that you are passing to `memberDropdownOptions(members)` is not defined when the function is being called.

Is `members` relying on some asynchronous logic to be given a value? Trace back to where it's being assigned a value, and make sure `memberDropdownOptions()` only fires once it does have one.

Comment: So do you recommend that instead of changing any of the function code I should just change the usage to `let memberOptions: Option[] = []
  // Check if members is undefined
  if (members) memberOptions = memberDropdownOptions(members)`

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the rest of the code, but personally, when making a function, I would never allow an opportunity for the argument to be undefined. 

Look at your parameter `(members: Person[])`. The type is `Person[]`, NOT `Person[] | undefined`.

Change your code outside of this function to ensure that your argument is never undefined.

Does TypeScript not throw an error saying that `members` may be undefined? If not, you might have incorrectly built your type/interface. Just keep going up the chain, console logging so you can find out where it is not being assigned.